# Cannot install PyAutoGUI

Tags: python, installation, pyautogui

I tried installing PyAutoGUI-0.9.35 but the following came up when running cmd in the same folder:

my input: pip install PyAutoGUI-0.9.35

output:

Collecting PyAutoGUI-0.9.35
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PyAutoGUI-0.9.35 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for PyAutoGUI-0.9.35

I then tried running the setup.py file from PyAutoGUI folder, but this showed up this time:

`usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [opts2_opts]...]
or: setyp.py --help [cmd1 cmd2...]
or: setup.py --help-commands
or: setup.py cmd --help`

error: no commands supplied

the window immediately shut down so I had to take a quick screenshot

could anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong? I run python 3.6, the required version for pyautogui is 3.4, I also run Win 10.

Comment: have you tried just "pip install pyautogui" ?

Comment: @Ajax1234 That worked, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
pip install pyautogui==0.9.35
```

Here's what happened when I did in a cmd session:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Windows\System32>pip install PyAutoGUI-0.9.35
Collecting PyAutoGUI-0.9.35
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PyAutoGUI-0.9.35 (from
 versions: )
No matching distribution found for PyAutoGUI-0.9.35

C:\Windows\System32>pip install pyautogui==0.9.35
Collecting pyautogui==0.9.35
  Downloading PyAutoGUI-0.9.35.zip (57kB)
    100% |################################| 61kB 223kB/s
Collecting pymsgbox (from pyautogui==0.9.35)
  Downloading PyMsgBox-1.0.6.zip
Collecting PyTweening>=1.0.1 (from pyautogui==0.9.35)
  Downloading PyTweening-1.0.3.zip
Requirement already satisfied: Pillow in c:\python35\lib\site-packages (from pya
utogui==0.9.35)
Collecting pyscreeze (from pyautogui==0.9.35)
  Downloading PyScreeze-0.1.9.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: olefile in c:\python35\lib\site-packages (from Pi
llow->pyautogui==0.9.35)
Building wheels for collected packages: pyautogui, pymsgbox, PyTweening, pyscree
ze
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for pyautogui ... done
  Stored in directory: C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\pip\Cache\wheels\28\
3b\07\64bee61ca73d56260a47d6b49692e7f217a69568aae2117167
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for pymsgbox ... done
  Stored in directory: C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\pip\Cache\wheels\c1\
cb\86\c3c2e3c39f9f0d015cf0f94ab6ca41e14f8c2083846e82b91d
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for PyTweening ... done
  Stored in directory: C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\pip\Cache\wheels\04\
86\59\70a93cd378740b5266c51e11c36ee3fc8b9dfef4b3bc72fd82
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for pyscreeze ... done
  Stored in directory: C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\pip\Cache\wheels\6a\
f7\db\9521ae30a53499f6c9024df5f5a605d56b6e6ad0c2d48dcb42
Successfully built pyautogui pymsgbox PyTweening pyscreeze
Installing collected packages: pymsgbox, PyTweening, pyscreeze, pyautogui
Successfully installed PyTweening-1.0.3 pyautogui-0.9.35 pymsgbox-1.0.6 pyscreez
e-0.1.9

C:\Windows\System32>
```

Answer (score 1):

**1. Method**

If your Python is not updated, then update your Python, then install **pyaudiogui**.

**2. Method**

```
pip install pyautogui==0.9.35
```